# How to create a Conda environment based on a YAML file?

Tags: python, yaml, conda

I am working on a online course and the instructors have asked me to create a Conda environment, and they have provided a YAML file to provide the library and package requirements for the Conda package.

However, I am unable to find a way to create the environment using the YAML file.

Comment: It is unclear to what 'the same' refers to, are these requirements for the YAML file, or the online course, or maybe even the conda environment? Apart from being unclear using "the same" instead of "this" (equally vague), sounds wrong to me (but I am not a native speaker)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`conda env create` takes an optional flag `--file`:

> -f FILE, --file FILE  environment definition file (default: environment.yml)

So do:

```
conda env create --file=myfile.yaml
```

Of course, replace `=myfile.yaml` with your YAML file name.

Answer (score 34):

Use:

```
conda env create --name NAME --file FILE
```

where `FILE` is the YAML file and `NAME` is what you want to name the environment.

(The accepted answer used to suggest `conda create`, but that only works on the output of `conda list --explicit`, not on Conda environment YAML files.)

Answer (score 3):

```
conda env create --file=dand-env-win.yaml
```

worked well for me where my file name was `dand-env-win.yaml` for a [course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud170/lessons/5430778793/concepts/54140889150923) on the Internet.